# Xcode won't compile or index project

Tags: xcode, macos

I've been programming with C++ in Xcode for quite sometime now.  Just recently Xcode hasn't been indexing my projects at all.  It will start to index but will immediately hang and not continue.

[image: Indexing project hangs]

When trying to compile the project, the compiler also hangs.

[image: Compiling project hangs]

I have tried clearing the Derived Data (and all organizer data for that matter) and nothing has worked.  I did not do anything to start this problem, it has come up completely randomly.

The console was spitting out an error every time I would try to compile the project (you can view below).  It would stop when I stopped the compilation

> 2/21/13 8:44:56.383 PM Xcode:  DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-2108/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/SpecificationTypes/XCGccMakefileDependencies.m:87
>   Details:  Failed to load dependencies output contents from ``/Users/Walker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-hinpckyvtyjoqgcoykprkexcwzvn/Build/Intermediates/HelloWorld.build/Debug/HelloWorld.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ship.d''. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “ship.d” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo=0x403ea95c0 {NSFilePath=/Users/Walker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-hinpckyvtyjoqgcoykprkexcwzvn/Build/Intermediates/HelloWorld.build/Debug/HelloWorld.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ship.d, NSUnderlyingError=0x403e9e960 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}. User info: {
>       NSFilePath = "/Users/Walker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-hinpckyvtyjoqgcoykprkexcwzvn/Build/Intermediates/HelloWorld.build/Debug/HelloWorld.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ship.d";
>       NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"";
>   }.
>   Function: void XCGccMakefileDependenciesParsePathsFromRuleFile(NSString *, void (^)(NSString *))
>   Thread:   {name = (null), num = 15}
>   Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.

I filed a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com, but Its been a few days and I haven't gotten any news on anything.  If you need *any* additional information I would be glad to provide it.  Thanks!

PS:  When I say hangs, it does not move.  It isn't slow or anything it is just completely freezes until I quit Xcode (when starting it up again the same thing happens).  I have also tried doing a clean re-install of Xcode

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are using LLVM 4.2.  If so, what do you have for your Optimization level?  I had a similar issue before and setting it to "None" solved it.

Comment: I have had it set to "none"